# How to Show Final Result separately in a Main Textbox Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a booking flight form. that takes the count of travellers . I created 3 textboxes to take travellers counts. it works good but the problem is i want to show each count of each category of travel in the textbox separately. for example when the user add a adult the adult count add to the textbox or when the child added the user can see the result in one text box. but my code reuturns total value. how can i change my code ?
here is my snippet :

```js
  $(function() {
  $(".button-click a").on("click", function() {
    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $button.closest("ul").prev().val();

    if ($button.text() == "+") {
      var newVal = parseInt(oldValue) +1;

    } else {
      // Don't allow decrementing below zero
      if (oldValue > 0) {
        var newVal = parseInt(oldValue - 1);
      } else {
        newVal = 0;
      }
    }
    $button.closest("ul").prev().val(newVal);
    
    //Calculate total travellers from all traveller textbox.
    var total_value = 0;
    //Loop through all the traveller textboxes
    $(".cat_textbox").each(function(){
      //Make addition of travellers from all the three textboxes
      total_value += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    //Assign the total traveller number to main textbox
    $(".main").val(total_value);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
Count all1 Traveller(s)
<input type="text" name="no_travellers" class="main" value="1 adult + 2 child + 1 infant" placeholder="" />
</label>
<br/><br/>
<label>
Adults
<input type="text" class="cat_textbox" id="CAT_Custom_410672" name="CAT_Custom_410672" maxlength="4000" value="0" />
 <ul class="button-group button-click">
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-plus"><span class="hide">+</span></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-minus"><span class="hide">-</span></i></a></li>
  </ul>
  </label>
  
  <label>
  Children 
  <input type="text" class="cat_textbox" id="CAT_Custom_410672" name="CAT_Custom_410672" maxlength="4000" value="0" />
   <ul class="button-group button-click">
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-plus"><span class="hide">+</span></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-minus"><span class="hide">-</span></i></a></li>
  </ul>
  </label>
  
  
    <label>
   Infants  
    <input type="text" class="cat_textbox" id="CAT_Custom_410672" name="CAT_Custom_410672" maxlength="4000" value="0" />
   <ul class="button-group button-click">
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-plus"><span class="hide">+</span></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-minus"><span class="hide">-</span></i></a></li>
  </ul>
  </label>
```

Comment: What output you actually need here?

Comment: @AKA  count of each travel seperately for example : 1child+2 adult + 0 infant . i wrote a code but it returns the total count

Comment: @inaz check my answer below. You wand that childe, adult part with the output too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? I shortened the code a bit. I wrapped the `label` texts in a span to properly select them.

**EDIT:** So the string in your `total input field` is dynamic because it uses the string in your `label` tags.

**EDIT2:** Added default value.

Here is a working fiddle:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".button-click a").on("click", function() {
    var button = $(this);
    var oldVal = parseInt(button.closest("ul").prev().val());
    var newVal = (button.text() == "+") ? oldVal+1: (oldVal > 0) ? oldVal-1 : 0;
    var total_value = "";
    
    button.closest("ul").prev().val(newVal);

    $(".cat_textbox").each(function(){
      var cat = $(this).prev('span').text();
      total_value += cat + ": " + $(this).val() + ", "; 
    });
    
    total_value = total_value.substring(0, total_value.length - 2);
    $(".main").val(total_value);
  })
});
```

```css
.main{
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
Count all1 Traveller(s)
<input type="text" name="no_travellers" class="main" value="Adults: 1" placeholder="" />
</label>
<br/><br/>
<label>
<span>Adults</span>
<input type="text" class="cat_textbox" id="CAT_Custom_410672" name="CAT_Custom_410672" maxlength="4000" value="1" />
 <ul class="button-group button-click">
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-plus"><span class="hide">+</span></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-minus"><span class="hide">-</span></i></a></li>
  </ul>
  </label>
  
  <label>
  <span>Children</span>
  <input type="text" class="cat_textbox" id="CAT_Custom_410672" name="CAT_Custom_410672" maxlength="4000" value="0" />
   <ul class="button-group button-click">
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-plus"><span class="hide">+</span></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-minus"><span class="hide">-</span></i></a></li>
  </ul>
  </label>
  
  
    <label>
   <span>Infants</span>
    <input type="text" class="cat_textbox" id="CAT_Custom_410672" name="CAT_Custom_410672" maxlength="4000" value="0" />
   <ul class="button-group button-click">
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-plus"><span class="hide">+</span></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-minus"><span class="hide">-</span></i></a></li>
  </ul>
  </label>
```

Comment: exactly this is what i want . but how can i show a value as default ? i want to show : 1 adult as default text .

Comment: Just insert your default value again in the total input ad change the default value of the adult input accordingly =)